# How can I convert Facebooks Graph API JSON data to find a user that already exists in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, facebook-graph-api

Alright, Iv'e done some research but still no luck...

I'll explain what I'm trying to do first:

I have an app which is sign in through Facebook only. I would like these users to see a list of their friends that are using my application as well.

I have routed `users#index` to return a list of users friends that are currently on the application. This is displayed in `JSON Data`. This data is returned as follows: `"name"=>"Example Name", "id"=>"32938293828393"`. In my database, I store all users `Facebook uid's`. I'd now like to be able to find a user by matching the returned `JSON id`, by matching it with the `uid` that iv'e stored in the database.

This is my current `users_controller.rb`:

```
def index
   @users = current_user.facebook.get_connections("me", "friends")
   @value = '{"id":"name"}'
   json = JSON.parse(@value).with_indifferent_access
   @users.find(params[json[:id] == :uid]) 
end
```

and this is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= link_to user.first_name, user %>
<% end %>
```

Iv'e been trying to do this for the past day with no luck... Done a lot of research. If there is a resource online explaining how to handle this, please drop a link below. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! Will post an answer for anyone else who may need help in the future with a similar problem..

In my `users_controller.rb` I now have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @friends = current_user.facebook.get_connections("me", "friends")
      uids = @friends.collect { |f| f["id"] }
      registered_friends = User.where('uid IN (?)', uids)
      @pals = registered_friends
   end
end
```

And now in my `Users/index.html.erb` I now have

```
<% @pals.each do |pal| %>
   <%= link_to pal.first_name, wall_path(pal.id) %>
<% end %>
```